# Find a text substring between two strings (RegExp)

Tags: regex

There is a string of text

asd2qw**d2er234**568678234111

How to apply `d2*234` through RegExp to get `“d2er234”` and not `“d2qwd2er234”` ?

This `d2.+?234` produces `d2qwd2er234`

How to limit the last occurrence of d2? Something like `(d2)(not(d2)).+?234`

Comment: Since regex works left to right I guess you would want to make sure `d2` does not occur nomore between `d2` and `234`. So one way would be a negative lookahead. Try: `d2(?!.*d2.*).*?234`

Comment: JvdV, thanks, your method is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed):

```
d2(?:(?!d2).)*?234
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/Wlzvtd/1)

Comment: @qweqwe1: You're welcome, glad it helps, feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)